# How can I convert a solid-black and white image into a collection of polygons?

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing

I have a bunch of solid-black and white images with various text and shapes on them. My goal is to convert each image into a set of polygons(defined as a set of vertices) that surround the black area (in the same way that a magic-wand tool can select areas in photo editing software).

I would prefer to implement this in JavaScript, but I am most interested in conceptually how I might go about doing this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The way magic wand works in simple bitmap editors is:

Let color C be the color of the original point selected.
Let last color LC be any color.

1. Get selected point (x,y)
2. If color of (x,y) = C and pixel not visited

   1. Store coordinates in array
   2. Repeat algorithm for (x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)
3. Store pixel in an array of visited pixels
4. If color of (x,y) != LC

   1. Mark pixel as border pixel in array
   2. Set LC = color of (x,y)

Comment: Aka floodfill. But this doesn't really produce polygons, does it?

Comment: @Junuxx It selects all pixels that match a color, in OP's case black. I am not sure if an array of pixels that represent polygons counts as "polygons". If he wants to select the surrounding shape, he would simply invert the condition.

Comment: I thought OP was really looking for the polyline "surrounding the black area". Maybe @cmpolis can explain.

Comment: @Junuxx I have added a pretty crude way of marking border pixels, can you think of anything better? How is this done in magic wand?

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful responses! I should have specified: I am looking to define each polygon as a set of **vertices**.

Comment: @cmpolis better, but how many vertices? Technically, if you have all border pixels you will have a polygon defined by its vertices; there's just a lot of them.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer doesn't give _structure_ to the perimeter. It gives a set of pixels, which e.g. in case of tracing the letter **A** in large enough font also reports the inner outline of the hole.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Is that not desirable? The hole is a polygon, a convex one, as opposed to the concave one formed by the negative space around an `A`

Comment: @Asad: maybe it's desirable -- however, the structure i.e. the relation between each pixel in the perimeter is still missing: what about figure 8, which has 2 holes?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Again, those are two separate whitespace polygons. A white rectangle with a figure 8 contains 3 whitespace polygons; a concave one external to the character, and two concave ones inside it.

Comment: Maybe there's no need to address items with holes. If that's the meaning of "solid". However objects with holes and islands having lakes with islands can be handled iteratively by floodfilling the outer perimeter with the opposite color and then finding all non connected areas, tracing them and floodfilling again.

Comment: @Asad Ideally I would have as few vertices as possible such that straight lines are defined with two vertices and rounded edges contain enough vertices to appear smooth.


However, having an inefficient(in terms of # of vertices) algorithm would still be acceptable - as long as the straight lines still appear smooth. Also, 'islands' can be ignored, ie if there is white completely inside black, it can be ignored. THANKS!

Comment: Once you have border pixels, you can apply the Douglas-Puecker algorithm to simplify the edges and produce vertices of polygons. Is that what you're looking for? 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

When only the perimeter must be scanned, one can produce a 'right hand on the wall' algorithm.

Step 1: traverse along the image right to find the first pixel of opposite color.
Step 2: Search all neighbouring pixels of the current one in clockwise order.
Step 3: Move to first available pixel. Store the pixel index
Step 4: Repeat steps 2-3 until the current pixel is the starting pixel in step 1

Step 5: Detect patterns from the stored pixels e.g.
Runs of LLLLLLLLLL, [Left] Up,Right or Down,

Patterns of form

```
RRRRRRR U RRRRRRR U RRRRRRRR U RRRRRRR U ...
<-N--->   <--N-->   <--N+1->   <--N-->
```

can be modelled by a line, although it is not that easy to do "inverse bresenham" to detect the best possible starting and ending points of a line segment.

A brute force approach can be anyway used to draw a line from current pixel to N previous pixels and test if bresenhams algorithm produces exactly the same pixels.

Comment: When you say `search all neighbouring pixels of the current one in clockwise order`, does that include diagonal pixels?

Comment: I meant 4-neighborhood. Maybe the algorithm would work for diagonals too.

Comment: This is probably the best approach because it is semantically closest to reconstructing a polygon through its border.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me explain what an "edge" is.

An edge is the virtual line between two contiguous pixels.

```
+---+---+
| A | B |  // The middle line is the edge between pixel A and pixel B
+---+---+
```

Edges have a starting point and an end point, and so are oriented upward, downward, "left going" or "right going".

In order to handle polygons crossing image boundaries, we gonna add a 1 pixel white border around our image.

Here is the algorithm:

```
For each row of our image {  
  For each pixel of the row except the last one {  
    If current pixel is white and next pixel is black {
      Create a new upward edge between the two pixels and add it to
      the global edge list.
    }
    Else if current pixel is black and next pixel is white {
      Create a new downward edge between the two pixels and add it to
      the global edge list.
    }
  }  
}
For each column of our image {  
  For each pixel of the column except the last one {  
    If current pixel is white and next pixel is black {
      Create a new "left going" edge between the two pixels and add it to
      the global edge list.
    }
    Else if current pixel is black and next pixel is white {
      Create a new "right going" edge between the two pixels and add it to
      the global edge list.
    }
  }  
}  

For each edge of the global edge list {
  Find the edge starting from the point where your current edge ends
  (for now on, we gonna call it next_edge).
  Connect the two edges to form a linked list
  (edge->next = next_edge; next_edge->previous = edge;)
}

While there is edges in the global edge list {
  Create a new polygon and add it to the polygon list
  Take the first edge of the list (for now on, we gonna call it first_edge)
  For each edge in the linked list starting at first_edge {
     Remove edge from global edge list
     Add edge to polygon's edge list
  }
}
```

Done, you have a list of polygons.

**EDIT**

Of course, you have to optimize it a little before using it, but it's really easy : consecutive edges with the same orientation can be replaced with a single, longer edge.

Comment: What about diagonal edges or lines going from (0,0)->(10,3) ?

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Wouldn't all edges be orthonormal, since pixels are square?

Comment: @Asad: In some context yes, but IMO the meaningful interpretation of OP's question deals e.g. with vectorizing a triangle into three vertices.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen Once you turned bitmap into "lossless" polygons as I do in this algorithm, you can further simplify it to _approximate_ original rasterized shapes by smoothing and remove irrelevant points. But that's a totally different question IMO. OP talked about "magic wand", and it's exactly what it does.